# Default Handler - fetch tag name

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am implementing a Default Handler in Android. My xml doc looks like -

```
<item>
     <rating>1</rating>
     <num>20</num>
</item>
```

I am overriding the characters method to fetch tag values for rating and num tags.

```
 public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) 
 {
      String value = new String(ch,start,length);
 }
```

but how can i check if this value belongs to rating or the num tag ?

Example if String 'value' gets some value (10 or b) how do i fetch the tagname ie (Rating or num) ?

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. You should parse xml tags to get values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String startName;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
String qName, Attributes attributes)
throws SAXException {
startName=qName;
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) 
 {
      //here check what the startName is.It can be rating or Num
      String value = new String(ch,start,length);
 }
```